# Capture custom event at dom-bind

Tags: javascript, polymer, dom-events, polymer-1.0

I am trying to capture custom-event at app level (dom-bind). I tried to capture the event in below two methods and both did not work.

1.

```
<template id="app" is="dom-bind" on-my-custom-event="handleEvent">
```

2.

```
app.addEventListener('my-custom-event', function(e){});
```

Plunker with demonstration: http://plnkr.co/edit/a5Ycs2p4fDaVZPqMNj2z

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't catch events emitted by a `template` element's children since the element's content is static. It is only when the `template`'s content is stamped in the DOM (that is, outside of the `template` element) that the events will/can be emitted.

Comment: Thanks for your response. A counter argument can be made that dom-bind is an element so listening to custom events should work on dom-bind.